# Should Response be imported or mocked when using unittest.mock

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm learning `unittest` and `unittest.mock` with the latter not quite clicking.

I'm mocking the response of an end-point and had the following:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

class CoreTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @patch('core.views.CoreViewSet.list')
    def test_response(self, mock_get):
        mock_get.return_value = [{'hello': 'world'}]
        client = APIClient()
        response = client.get('/core/')
        print(response.data)
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'list'>`
```

Made sense because DRF uses `Response`.

To get around the error I modified to:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CoreTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @patch('core.views.CoreViewSet.list')
    def test_response(self, mock_get):
        mock_get.return_value = Response([{'hello': 'world'}])
        client = APIClient()
        response = client.get('/core/')
        print(response.data)
```

Which achieved the desired result and I was just passing in an array of objects (or list of dicts).

However, I'm not sure this was the correct way of handling this and if `Mock()` should have been used instead. I can honestly say I haven't been able to figure out how to use `Mock()` or `MagicMock()` correctly, or find a tutorial that explains it clearly, so my attempts at using it with:

```
mock_get.return_value = Mock([{'hello': 'world'}])
```

Just resulted in:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions about how this test should be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

> AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'list'>`

This error comes from `isinstance` assertion [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/views.py#L423).

## Solution

If you want to use `Mock` or `MagicMock` to mock `Response` and pass `isinstance` check, you can use `spec` or `spec_set` parameter when creating a mock response.

```py
class CoreTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @patch('core.views.CoreViewSet.list')
    def test_response(self, mock_get):
        mock_get.return_value = Mock(spec=Response, data=[{'hello': 'world'}])
        ...
```

## Notes

When creating a `Mock` or `Magic`, you should pass the property name of what you want to mock as keyword arguments. In this case, you want to mock `Response.data`, therefore you should set `Mock(data=<DATA_VALUE>)`. Otherwise, the value will be passed to `Mock` positional arguments.

The official python documentation also provides clear examples of how to use `mock` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html).